# Change session number of running application

Tags: windows-7, session

We use Microsoft's Store Operations.
The HQ Server has to be kept running for connections from our stores to be successful.
Every now and then we come up with a problem where the server application must be restarted, which I often do via remote desktop. Is there any way to move that application to the console session?
Is there any way that the session number of a running application can be changed to a different user?

Comment: So hand off the running application to another user? What is your use case here?

Comment: We use Microsoft's Store Operations. The HQ Server has to be kept running for connections from our stores to be successful. Every now and then we come up with a problem where the server application must be restarted, which I often do via remote desktop. Is there any way to move that application to the console session?